# No Sales Order Table in magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2

Why there is no sales_order table in phpmyadmin magento 2 database or is it there with different naming conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png shows tables in a diagram, I can see sales_flat_order table for instance. Also sales_order_* something. Hope that helps.